# Sentry compile fails with " error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1"

Tags: python-2.7, gcc, centos, sentry

Been trying to install Sentry on CentOS 6.5. I have installed the prerequisites i.e Python 2.7.9

[root@localhost poduori]# python -V
Python 2.7.9

I used pyenv to change from the pre-installed python version 2.6.6 (pyenv install 2.7.9). When I try to install sentry I get the below output and error;
NB: I had already run it once hence it using cached.

pip2.7 install sentry

The full error output can be found here https://www.dropbox.com/s/64w6b7dswgzs9cb/Sentry_error.txt?dl=0

or

[Sentry error txt file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/64w6b7dswgzs9cb/Sentry_error.txt?dl=0)

A summary of the error I'm getting is below

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/root/.pyenv/versions/2.7.9/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-PSGsNT/cffi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-UYMAyw-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-PSGsNT/cffi
```

The output was too long to post here so I used dropbox instead.

libffi is already installed. 
root@localhost user]# rpm -qa|grep libffi
libffi-3.0.5-3.2.el6.x86_64

I already installed all the development tools, 
yum groupinstall "Development tools" (including gcc compiler) but I still get the same error. Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

```
ERROR: /bin/sh: xslt-config: command not found
** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

c/_cffi_backend.c:13:17: error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
```

You need to install dev packages first one (it let you out of this w/ pre-built libs) is libxslt-dev, second one is python-dev. Exact names depends on your distro.

Comment: python-devel is already installed "[root@localhost poduori]# rpm -qa|grep python-devel
python-devel-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64
[root@localhost poduori]#
"  and "[root@localhost poduori]# rpm -qa|grep  libxslt-dev
libxslt-devel-1.1.26-2.el6_3.1.x86_64
" are both installed but I'm still getting the error. Can the version difference affect it? I have both python-2.6.6 and pythton-2.7.9.

Comment: how you expect python-2.7.9 (that what pip-2.7 on top of your paste tells us) to use dev packages from python-2.6.6?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Installed python a fresh under /usr/local/bin. Defined the default paths.
[root@localhost poduori]# echo $PYTHONPATH
:/usr/local/bin/:/usr/local/bin/:/usr/local/bin/

[root@localhost poduori]#  echo $PYTHON_LIBDIR
/usr/local/lib

When I try and install python-devel via yum it fetched yum for 2.6.6 instead of 2.7.9 . What I'm I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Using ubuntu i solved this by:

Installing setuptools with :

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | python
```

created a file **requisits.sh**

inserted the content:

```
#! /bin/bash

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install setuptools
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo apt-get install libxslt1-dev
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
sudo apt-get install libz-dev
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

put execution `chmod +x requisits.sh`

executed:

```
./requisits.sh
```

entered the password and answered y/n when prompted.

and finally :

if using virtualenv:

```
pip install -U sentry
```

else

```
sudo pip install -U sentry
```